# Play audio file stored in SD Card memory on Zedboard

Tags: linux-kernel, fpga, mmap, fifo, dma

Is it possible to have a named pipe on my PS side of the Zedboard; that leads to a FIFO in the the PL side (using DMA,AXI,I2S etc) that I then revert to the audio out port and play songs from my PS side and listen from the audio out port on the PL side?

If yes then what steps are to be followed on the PS Side?

I'm guessing at mapping of user space into kernel space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it turns out that ANALOG DEVICES has just the stuff you need.

There is a different kernel that Analog Device's maintains, which
includes both ALSA drivers
for the audio chip (ADAU1761) and the HDMI output (ADV7511).

https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux

there are a few zynq branches in there. Normally Xilinx pulls drivers
from there for their kernels,
but anyone can do the same.

The build instructions (if that's the sort of thing you want to do) is
at:
http://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/ad-fmcomms2-ebz/software/linux/zynq_2014r2

Or, alternatively you could just download the ready-made image for your particular board from this dropbox link:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yfbpj63pcenqatr/AAAt0s3xFXs47I7q5pNopheHa?dl=0

After you download the file; uncompress it with this command:

```
unxz -d sdimage-8G-zedboard.direct.xz
```

Find out the name of your SD Card with this command:

```
dmesg|tail
```

And then write the resulting image to your 8GB SD Card with this command:

```
sudo dd if=sdimage-8G-zedboard.direct of=/dev/sdX
```

where `sdX` is your particular SDCard which you noted from command `dmesg|tail`
This command will erase all the pre-existing data on the sd card so make sure you have a backup if that data is important to you.

**WARNING**: *Please be VERY careful while using the `dd` command. Writing the image to the wrong `/dev/sdX` location could possibly lead to corruption of OS and/or the hardware also and is extremely risky.*

After you burn the image; you're good to go! A full-blown graphical linux environment will turn up ( You need to connect an HDMI display; and use USB OTG port to use the mouse and keyboard)

NOTE: You can also choose between what path you want your sound to play;
whether from the headphone jack or through the HDMI cable.